# How to display category name at details view using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

`ItemCategory` class :

```
   public class ItemCategory
   {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

`Item` class is as below:

```
   public class Item
   {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name ="Category Code")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
   }
```

This is the code from items controller:

```
   // GET: Items/Details/5
   public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
   {
      if (id == null)
      {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }

      var items =  db.Items.Include(i => i.ItemCategory);

      if (items == null)
      {
          return HttpNotFound();
      }

      //var thisItem = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ItemId == id);
      return View(await db.Items.FindAsync(id));
}
```

and view code is as below:

```
@model ContactManager.Models.Item
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h2>Details</h2>
<div>
    <h4>Item</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCategory.CategoryName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemCategory.CategoryName)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCode)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemCode)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemName)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BarCode)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BarCode)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ItemId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework. When I execute the code the view does not display the category name at this view, I really want to know how I can get the category name at this view ....thanks

Answer (score 0):

ItemCategory.CategoryName reference is null. Change your **Item** model . It will work.

```
  public class Item
    {
        public Item() // Note this
        {
            ItemCategory = new ItemCategory();
        }
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Category Code")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: check if 'db.Items.FindAsync(id)' returns your 'ItemCategory ' object and then what value is there in 'ItemCategory.CategoryName'.

Comment: Yes it returns ItemCategory but ItemCategory returns null value in the view.